# Buffer I/O error while booting from BackTrack 4.0 live CD using VirtualBox

Tags: linux, boot, virtualbox, buffer, backtrack

I am facing a problem while installing [BackTrack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BackTrack) 4.0 on my [VirtualBox](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) installation. After assigning a hard drive and booting from the [live CD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_CD), I am receiving a error message as follows.

```
Loading, please wait...
Buffer I/O error on device hdc, logical block 76636
(this statement gets repeated like four times with different logical block id. 
SQUASHFS error: squashfs_read_data failed to read block 0x5bb337b9
SQUASHFS error: unable to read is index table.
```

It is not the first time I install operating systems on VirtualBox though it is the first time I receive such an error with BackTrack.

Answer (score 1):

It may be due to a corrupted image. Compute the [MD5](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) hash value of the download (with [md5sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Md5sum)) and compare with the supplied MD5 hash value.